# AWS Glue: How to write to S3 cross account

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, identity-management

I have a Glue job in my account (Account-local), and I need to write the ETL output to another account (Account-remote). The job runs with an IAM role in local account: `Glue-job-role`

There is an IAM role in Account-remote, with name `External-clients-role`, which has policy providing permissions to S3 resource actions, such as:  `s3:PutObject`, `s3:GetObject` etc to the S3 bucket in Account-remote.

Additionally, in the Trust Relationship of `External-clients-role`, the local glue job role `Glue-job-role` is added as a Principal, with `sts:AssumeRole` action, as:

```
//External-client-role trust relationship:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_number>:role/Glue-Job-Role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

i.e., its expected that the clients of Account-remote would assume the role, and use that to write to S3 bucket. However, I am not able to figure out how to assume this role.

Queries:

Since `Glue-job` is running with a local IAM role for ETL steps, can it assume `External-clients-role` just for the part of writing to remote S3 ? If yes, how to do it? Is there any other way ? [image]

I  tried looking at resources on how to assume the remote account role, however not able to find good lead on it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Bucket policy for that case.

1. Add following bucket policy to a bucket on remote account:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGlueAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS-Local-account-id>:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Grant access to this bucket for AWS Glue, normally using the IAM Role that is assigned to the task.
3. Reuse your current Glue task code, as you don't need to change anything.

**This assumes you can create a bucket policy, which might be not true, at the same time it's the simplest approach.**

---

The second approach that would do it in a way, that you've tried, is to manually assume the role and overwrite credentials, however because I haven't tested it and I'm not sure if overwriting credentials is possible after reading data from data source, I'm only copy-pasting the link:

https://tmmr.uk/post/aws-glue-assume-temporary-credentials/